# how to save the output files in new folder?? now these are stored in root. guide me to save in specific location and i wanted to give file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

please help me to upgrade the below: this actually opens the website and took screenshot of it.

I need the o/p file to be saved in desired location. and if possible please help me with the name.

example : if input is: https://www.amazon.in/B078BNQ318/ i want the file saved as B078BNQ318. Kindly help

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui, time
import xlrd

URL = []
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

# change the loc as per your excel location
loc = ("C:\\Users\\dilip\\Documents\\URL.xlsx")
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
# open the first sheet
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    URL.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))

for i in range(0, len(URL)):
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(URL[i])
    time.sleep(5)
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    filename = "file" + str(i) + ".png"
    screenshot.save(filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use f string in python.

```
for i in range(0, len(URL)):
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(URL[i])
    time.sleep(5)
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    filename = "file" + str(i) + ".png"
    screenshot.save(f"D:\\{filename}")   # Here I gave D drive as location.Change this acccording to your need
```

Comment: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can use split on the path and get the last element.
I don't understand the code, so I'm gonna say what I understand

```
#assume this is the url

url = 'https://www.amazon.in/B078BNQ318/'
i = url.split('/')

#assuming all url's are like the example you gave 

filename = "file" + str(i[-2]) + ".png"

#output of i = ['https:', '', 'www.amazon.in', 'B078BNQ318','']
```